# oracle temporary table in read only environment

Tags: oracle, temp-tables

Our database environment contains a primary and a reporting site which is synchronized. primary is read/write and reporting read only. For creating reports I am only allowed to use the reporting site. Now I want to use temporary tables. I can create them on primary site and the synchronization mechanism moves it to reporting site. But due to missing permissons I cant fill them. Is there a way (role concept, special permissions...) that makes it possible in Oracle to use temporary tables even the environment is read only? By the way, we are using Oracle 11.

Comment: What form of synchronization is in use?

Comment: for what you say, it looks like you are using Oracle Active Data Guard. If so, you can't. The standby site in read mode means that, read mode.

Comment: I'd just point out that, unlike other databases, it is really infrequent in Oracle that you'd want to use temporary tables in reports.  I've been working with Oracle for a couple of decades and been in lots of reporting environments and I don't think I've ever come across a report where I wanted to use a temporary table.

Comment: administrator said we use dataguard (but not active), prim is on primary and report on standby. If I get you right, on current configuration it's not possible to use temporary tables, the way I want it too. If we go to the latestet Oracle version (19?) would it be possible? Or what would you recommend to do if we install a newer version?

Comment: @Justin: what would you recommend? Materialized Views?

Comment: _"what would you recommend?"  It's hard to make a recommendation until you explain exactly why you think you need a temp table and how you plan to use it.

Comment: @user , if you are using Oracle Data Guard, but not ACTIVE, then the standby database cannot be opened. if you have your standby in status open read, it means that you are using ACTIVE DATA GUARD .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I'm working on the assumption you are using Standby database not your own home grown option)*

Oracle 11 you are in trouble :-)

With 12.1 and above, we have a thing called temporary undo ( see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/undo.htm#CEGJGIAE )

With temporary undo, the process you are following will work because both the redo and undo are housed in your temp tablespace on your read only environment.

Perhaps a better option is to upgrade to 19c, where we have a thing call standby DML redirect where we intercept the DML aiming at the standy, redirect it to the primary which is then replayed back to the standby.

You can get an overview of these here

https://youtu.be/-B9eorpmikU

Comment: I think I have all informationen I was looking for. You're wright, Oracle 11 wasn't my choise.